# Can the check-in agent at the airport see at what price the passenger has purchased the flight ticket?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airports, check-in, price

Can the check-in agent at the airport see at what price the passenger has purchased the flight ticket?

Comment: Which airline, which airport, (in case there are differences.)

Comment: @Willeke I was asking for the general case, but if that indeed depends on the airline and airport: SFO with United Airlines.

Comment: My guess is that most probably yes, if they want to.

Answer (score 2):

In almost all cases the answer is yes. The check in agent has full access to the ticket details including the fare class and the specific conditions & restrictions. Otherwise, they wouldn't be able to do any type of changes, upgrades, re-bookings, etc.